# Why do look up tables speed things up compared to brute force?

Tags: brute-force-attack, complexity

I'm currently reading up on lookup tables and efficiency. In my uni script it says the following:

For **Brute Force**:

- Preparation time: $O(1)$
- Disk space requirement: $O(1)$
- Time required to crack the password: $O(2^n)$

Full **lookup table**:

- Preparation time: $O(2^n)$
- Disk space requirement: $O(2^n)$
- Time required to crack the password: $O(1)$

I'm not sure I'm understanding this correctly.

As far as I understand, for Brute Force:

$O(1)$ is the time required to look up the password in my table of all possible passwords.
The disk space requirement is simply as large as needed for a list of all possible passwords, so $O(1)$ as well

My questions:

Why is the time needed to crack the password $O(2^n)$? How is it determined?

It seems I don't understand the concept of a lookup table either. As far as I see, a lookup table will simply hash the full list of possible passwords (so required disk space is larger) but what then? Why is the cracking of the password per se faster?

I think I'm missing something crucial here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: n-bit input so you need to look for $2^n$ possible passwords.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose you have an $n$-bit key. Suppose further you have some reliable predicate $P(k,m)$ which decides whether a key $k$ is *the* key you are looking for given the reference $m$. Furthermore, suppose you have a "successor" function $F$, that takes a key and returns you the "next" key so that eventually all keys are traversed.

Now what a brute-force attack does is, given $m$, it takes a starting key $k$, evaluates $P(k,m)$ if it returns false, sets $k\gets F(k)$. This will take $\mathcal O(2^n)$ evaluations of $P$ and $F$. Assuming both can be computed in $\mathcal O(1)$ the entire calculation takes $\mathcal O(2^n)$.

Now for the look-up table. For this you simply start at some key $k$, and store the $m$ such that $P(k,m)$ yields true as a pair $(m,k)$ in a giant array (or [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)). Now you repeat this with $F(k)$. When you then get a concrete $m$, you simply look it up in the table and find the corresponding $k$. For hashmaps and continuous arrays, this takes time $\mathcal O(1)$ (ie the lookup time is independent of the number of elements). Clearly, you need storage for all the $2^n$ pairs of $(m,k)$. Now the preparation time assumes that you can find $m$ such that $P(k,m)$ is true, but this is usually possible in constant time, e.g. by evaluating a hash function or an encryption cipher.

Comment: For Hash table [hash table runtime complexity; insert, search and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214353/hash-table-runtime-complexity-insert-search-and-delete)

Answer (score 2):

## Brute Force

Let's say your password was all digits (e.g. 607552)

If your password has length 1, it will take up to 10 attempts to crack:

```
0, 1, 2, 3 ..., 9
```

If your password has length 2, it will take up to 100 attempts to crack

```
00, 01, 02, ... 10, 11, 12, ... 20, 21, 22, ... 99
```

If your password has length 3 it will take up to 1000 attempts to crack

See the pattern? The number of attempts is $10^n$. It's the same idea if you are cracking a password with $n$ bits. (Since a bit can be 0 or 1, instead of 0-9, it's a power of 2 instead of 10).

## Lookup Table

While a brute-force attack **tries** all possible **passwords** to see if they produce the right hash, a lookup table is a fast way to do the opposite: get a password based on a hash. It does this by hashing all the possible passwords ahead of time, *and storing the results in a table*.

**Method 1:**

Store the items in an array, **sorted by hash**. When given a hash, *guess* the position in the array of this hash, based on the numerical value of the hash. (I.e. if the numerical value is 25% of the maximum value the hash could be, then you would guess the index that is 25% of the total array size.) Your guess will be very close, because any good hash is evenly distributed. Go forwards or backwards until you find a match. This is freakishly close to $O(1)$, especially if you refine your guesses (binary-search-style) rather than just incrementing or decrementing.

The main disadvantage of this method is that initially sorting the table is asymptotically slower than generating it, namely $O(2^n \times \log (2^n)) = O(n 2^n)$.

**Method 2:**

This is essentially a hashmap, except using a library hashmap is silly when you already have a hash! Just use the first $n$ digits of your hash. That means: create an array of size $2^n$. In each slot goes a list of all hashes whose first $n$ digits equal that array index. (And their corresponding passwords.)

To look up a hash, take its first $n$ digits, and get the corresponding list out of the array. Traverse the list to find the hash. Like a hashmap, this takes $O(1)$ constant amortised time.